# Internet Explorer is not launching my selenium webdriver code

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

[image]
**Selenium WebDriver code is:**

```
File file = new File("D:\\Polycom_Space\\WebdriversIEDriverServer_x64_2.53.1\\IEDriverServer.exe");

System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",file.getAbsolutePath());
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "IE");
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
capabilities.setCapability("requireWindowFocus", true);
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(host, capabilities);



**//grid node configuration is---**

cd Polycom_Space\Java Libraries Server
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar -role webDriver -hub http://localhost:4242/grid/register -port 5557 -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=D:\Polycom_Space\Webdrivers

\IEDriverServer_x64_2.53.1\IEDriverServer.exe -browser browserName="internet explorer" -maxInstances=4 -maxSession 1
```

**Exception is:**

> org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadExecutionException: org.testng.internal.InvokeMethodRunnable$TestNGRuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error forwarding the new session cannot find : Capabilities [{ensureCleanSession=true, acceptSslCerts=true, requireWindowFocus=true, browserName=IE, version=, platform=WINDOWS}]

Comment: Kindly Help me to run Internet Explorer on Grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The -D properties should come before the jarfile (otherwise it is treated as an argument of the application, not an option of the JVM).
From java help, the usage is

```
java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
```

Try executing it with

```
java -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=D:\Polycom_Space\Webdrivers\IEDriverServer_x64_2.53.1\IEDriverServer.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar -role webDriver -hub http://localhost:4242/grid/register -port 5557 -browser browserName="internet explorer" -maxInstances=4 -maxSession 1
```

Comment: thanks bro for answer. still exception is throwing same after these changes in node file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your test code.

> Error forwarding the new session cannot find

is the grid's way of telling you that whatever node you requested for (based on your capability), the grid could not find in its farm of nodes.

Your test code is requesting for a browser whose name is **IE**, but the Grid has only one node which supports a browser named **internet explorer**

The line

> capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();

already takes care of setting the browser name properly.

So you don't need the below line (this is the line that is causing the issue) :

> capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "IE");

Please remove that line and try again.

Also its better to tweak your node capabilities via a nodeConfig JSON file rather than you trying to pass them via the command line (its easy to make mistakes when using the command line)

[This](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2#configuring-the-nodes-by-json) document should help you get oriented with JSON node configs.

Comment: thanks bro for answer. still exception is throwing same after these changes.

Comment: @AmarNathYadav - Can you please show the new stacktrace for your error? I am pretty sure, it will not be the same as what you have included in your question.